# LWC: Do I have to use a template element with if:true?

Tags: lightning-web-components, conditional

The Lightning Web Components Dev Guide gives this example in the article titled [Render HTML Conditionally](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_conditional), where a conditionally-rendered `div` element is wrapped in a `template` element containing an `if:true` attribute:

```html
<!-- helloConditionalRendering.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-card title="HelloConditionalRendering" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Show details" onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
            <template if:true={areDetailsVisible}>
                <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
                    These are the details!
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

In practice, you can add an `if:true` or `if:false` attribute to just about anything in LWC, and it will render or not render accordingly.  Is there anything wrong with this alternative version, where the `template` element is omitted and the `if:true` attribute is applied directly to the `div`?  If not, why does Salesforce promote a pattern that is more verbose and leads to deeper nesting in HTML templates?

```html
<!-- helloConditionalRendering.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-card title="HelloConditionalRendering" icon-name="custom:custom14">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Show details" onchange={handleChange}></lightning-input>
            <div if:true={areDetailsVisible} class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
                These are the details!
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you must use `<template>` for [conditional rendering](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-conditional.html). This change was made after the original answer was posted. In addition, the conditions `if:true` and `if:false` have now become `lwc:if`, `lwc:elseif`, and `lwc:else`. This fixes the situation where a developer used to be able to write `if:true` and `if:false` on the same element, which caused a runtime error if both were specified and certain conditions were met.

## Original Answer

No, you do not need to use `<template>` to host various attributes and directives, including `if:true`, `if:false`, `for:each`, `iterator:*`, `for:item`, `for:index`, or `key`. The documentation further doesn't explore any particular reason why you would want to use `<template>` for this purpose.

I think salesforce.com is trying to imply that it is "easier" or "more consistent to read," but, like you, I prefer my code to be as concise as possible, as long as legibility isn't sacrificed in the process. Establishing a clear pattern (e.g. listing such attributes upfront so they're more "visible," using appropriate indentation/line breaks/etc) can help avoid any confusion. It's more important to have a consistent style.

If you prefer the `<template>` model, feel free to use it, and if not, consider the alternatives acceptable. Just remember that you always have to obey any relevant rules (e.g. `for:each` must also have a `key` on the element).

Comment: @Domanell's new answer below seems to be calling out a recent change in the LWC docs. It looks like Salesforce is now explicitly saying we can use `lwc:if`, `lwc:elseif`, and `lwc:else` on essentially any kind of HTML tag. Do we need another revision to this answer?

Comment: @MatthewSouther Interestingly, my link still just says "nested `<template>` tag". There's a documentation bug somewhere. I'll ask.

Answer (score 1):

**lwc:if|elseif={expression} and lwc:else**

Conditionally render DOM elements in a template. `lwc:if`, `lwc:elseif`, and `lwc:else` supersede the `if:true` and `if:false` directives.

Use the conditional directives on nested `<template>` tags, `<div>` tags or other HTML elements, and on your custom components tags like `<c-custom-cmp>`.

[Directives for Nested Templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-directives.html#lwccolonifelseifexpression-and-lwccolonelse)