# When will if:true stop working?

Tags: lightning-web-components, rendering

As per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-conditional.html the legacy `if:true` directives are no longer recommended and must be replaced with `lwc:if` conditional directives.

However, I could not see a timeline for the same. This is a bit concerning because our org has a lot of custom lwcs that use the traditional `if:true` rendering and it would be a disaster if suddenly it stops working. So I needed to know when salesforce would no longer support this traditional rendering so that we could plan the migration to `lwc:if` accordingly.

Comment: What I would suggest is dont wait for it. Just do it in batches, if there are many `if:true`, so as to future proof your work. Just take it as a tech debt and finish it.

Comment: From what I have observed, salesforce might deprecate this, but to remove it fully from template xsd, that would be very much down the line and not any time soon.

Comment: @NagendraSingh It's not our place to say how far down the line, though. I've been doing Salesforce for 18 years, so when I hear that, I think we might still have these directives in 2033 or something. There's no justifiable reason to put off upgrading now, as even a thousand conditions can be upgraded in a day by a single developer.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes agreed, upgrade needs to be done as soon as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 2023-10-16, there is no ticking clock. Until salesforce.com officially announces deprecation, it is still technically safe to use `if:true` and `if:false`. After deprecation, we are guaranteed at least one release cycle, so your code will not "suddenly stop working" for at least four months after that. It's likely that the deprecation window would be one to three years. That said, you should plan to take some time for this now, while there isn't a time pressure.

After all, in one project I had, the project manager was concerned about my intent to replace all the `if:true` and `if:false` statements in our code base. There were hundreds of `if:true` and `if:false` directives. Fixing all of them took a work day, including testing. And that was by me alone, while the rest of the team worked on other tasks.

Here's possible situations you can encounter, and how to fix each of them.

## `<template if:true...`

You can replace these directly with `<template lwc:if...`.

## `<some-element if:true...`

The new directives don't like working on non-template elements, so wrap them in a `<template lwc:if...><some-element ...></template>`.

## `<template if:false...`

If you have a preceding `<template lwc:if...`, then this is most likely `<template lwc:else` or possibly `<template lwc:elseif...>`. It should be obvious from context if you you use code folding in your IDE. Otherwise, invert the logic in your controller and use `<template if:true`. This is very uncommon. In my last project where I dealt with this, there were less than a dozen examples out of the hundreds of conditions I found in our templates.

## `<some-element if:false...`

Again, you need to wrap them up in a `template`, and then follow the directions from the immediately preceding section.

---

That said, if you don't want to make an entire side project out of this, I'd just set a precommit hook to scan for any template files that have changed, see if they have an older directive, and have the commit fail if any are found. This would force developers to clean up the files as they develop new code.

A strategy of cleaning up as you go along will set you up for a scenario that when deprecation occurs, you'll already be done, or nearly done. Don't wait until the last minute to get started. It takes virtually no time at all, but if you wait until then, you might be caught off guard. As an analogy, consider the [The Hare & the Tortoise](https://read.gov/aesop/025.html). Deprecation is a slow process, but it can beat you to the finish line if you get complacent.

Comment: That "The new directives don't like working on non-template elements" is horrible to hear: is that bugs or by design? Having to extra elements for conditional logic is something from the dark ages IMO.

Comment: @KeithC It is an intentional change. The docs now read "To render HTML conditionally, add the lwc:if|elseif={property} and lwc:else directive to a nested `<template>` tag that encloses the conditional content." This was not previously true. I even wrote an [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/355221/2984) that I amended due to this change. I found out about it while doing the aforementioned update in the project I worked on.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Sad to hear, and a weird decision.